# Flags and Modifiers of printf in C

Tags: c, printf

I have a task of recoding printf with the majority of its functionality (in C). However, while doing some tests, I found a problem: I do not understand how the standard function behaves when the user puts more than 1 modifier (the allowed modifiers are h, hh, l, ll, z, and j).
For example:

```
printf("%hhld", 128) results in 128 printed out;  
printf("%lhhd", 128) results in 128 printed out;  
printf("%lhhd", 9223372036854775807) shows 9223372036854775807;  
printf("%lhhd", 9223372036854775808) shows -9223372036854775808;  
printf("%hhld", 9223372036854775807) shows 9223372036854775807;  
printf("%hhld", 9223372036854775808) shows -9223372036854775808;
```

What modifier will be chosen and how does printf choose it? Why would it always ignore hh in this situation?

Another question is whether my printf should work with flags and modifier in the random order or not? Because in wiki, the article mentions a certain order:

> > %[parameter][flags][width][.precision][length]type

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behavior, read the documentation.

Basically passing a parameter that has a different type than the one expected by the specifier is considered undefined behavior by the standard.

You are also mixing incompatible specifiers, again "*just read the documentation*", this is good documentation if you want to fully understand the behavior of [`printf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html).

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain it to me or pinpoint the exact line in the man? I have read it several times and still don't see the answer to my question.

Comment: In the docs linked by the answer above under section "*Length Modifier*" the phrase "*A following integer conversion corresponds to ...*" could be read as  "Use this length modifier only with ..." Your code does not comply to this rules. And with this invokes undefined behaviour.